# Firebase (Google) Cloud Messaging (FCM, old GCM) - check message status

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to find a solution to ensure a push notification to my Chrome extension has been received before sending another one. IF it hasn't been received and another one should go, I would change its content to tell the user he has multiple new informations to check.

So I'm looking for a way to check the previous message status using its ID, or check the queue of messages if using a collapse key, before sending a new one. But I can't find anything related to this, except here : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en there is FCM message status detailed, but no way to get them after the first response.

I am aware receipts can be implemented using [XMPP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) but I would really prefer to remain on the regular HTTP protocol.

Thanks ahead for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP receipts would be the recommended way for you to get an ack that the message was delivered. You can also use the [Play Developer console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) (Android developer console) to view statistics on the status of messages. However this will not be sufficient if you want to automatically resend, you would have to do this manually.

Comment: Thanks, after searching for a long time that was my conclusion as well, not doable ATM with the HTTP API. I will accept that answer then.